# ModRewrite display sub domain instead of a query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to grant each customer of mine with a sub domain in order to provide him with more easy access to my application.

For example, I would like

joseph.mysite.com/inex.php to be displayed at the address bar.
while the actual page location is www.mysite.com/index.php?customerId=102

same for 
joseph.mysite.com/personalArena.php => www.mysite.com/personalArena.php?customerId=102

Is there any way to append a query string to the domain depending of the sub domain that the user inputs?.

Thanks in advance,
Oleg.

Comment: This won't be possible unless you have mod_proxy enabled in your Apache config

Comment: My site is running on a Linode VPS, I'm reading into the [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)mode proxy  docs right[/link] now, assuming I will decide to enable it for this purpose, how to I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Also how to translate `joseph` to `102`?

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that your site is configured to accept the various subdomains you have set up (how to configure this can vary, from setting up an `ServerAlias` in the `VirtualHost` part of httpd.conf, using mod_proxy, etc), then the following will do *part* of what you want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*)\.php http://www.example.com/$0?cid=%1 [QSA]
```

Basically it will rewrite any .php request, and add `?cid=X`, where `X` is the first part of the domain... for example: `http://john.example.com/test.php` becomes `http://www.example.com/test.php?cid=john`.  This bit I have tested, and seems to work (for me).

The next bit is mapping the subdomain to a user ID.  There are various ways to do it, but a simple way is to have a text file which just lists the mapping:

```
john 123
joseph 102
oleg 179
```

Then, in your `httpd.conf` (important - RewriteMap won't work in `.htaccess`) you define this as a map:

```
RewriteMap useridmap txt:/path/to/useridmap.txt
```

After this has been done you can use the mapping in your rules, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*)\.php http://www.example.com/$0?cid=${useridmap:%1} [QSA]
```

*Should* replace "john" in the subdomain with "123" in the query string, and so on.

**Caveat**: I can't currently try this out, as I'm not at a server that I can easily configure.